# IWebBrowser2 textbox watermark removal

Tags: windows, iwebbrowser2

I have a native C++ app that authenticates a user using OAuth2 with various providers, which simply pops up a browser (`IWebBrowser2`) navigating to the target authentication server.  Everything works well, but I have not been able to determine why the watermark in the textbox remains while typing.

[image]

I implement the following interfaces:
   -- [IOleClientSite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693706(v=vs.85).aspx)
   -- [IOleInPlaceSite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686586(v=vs.85).aspx)
   -- [IDocHostUIHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753260(v=vs.85).aspx)
   -- [IOleInPlaceFrame](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692770(v=vs.85).aspx)
   -- [DWebBrowserEvents2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768283(v=vs.85).aspx)

I was suspicious of [IOleInPlaceFrame::TranslateAccelerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694390(v=vs.85).aspx) as well as [IDocHostUIHandler::TranslateAccelerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753266(v=vs.85).aspx), however these functions are not even called when the user is typing (breakpoints are never hit).  Nevertheless, I have tried various return values to ensure that the browser is allowed to handle all input, however I have not been able to resolve the issue.  Any help would be very appreciated.

**EDIT**:  In addition, tab is not moving focus either, forcing the user to use the mouse to navigate.  The 'x' on the right of the email functions properly when clicked.

Comment: Are you sure it's not caused by the page itself? or/and by what version of IE the page thinks it's talking to, check this out: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/may/21/web-browser-control-specifying-the-ie-version

Comment: @SimonMourier - Outstanding article.  You make a great point.  Hoping this was the issue, I added my app to the list in HKLM with 11000 (dec), and rebooted just to be sure, however no change (sigh).  I am running Win10 build 14393.  Same behavior on Win7.  Of course this doesn't happen when logging into something using only the standalone browser (i.e. logging into Office365).  I still think that you may be right.

Comment: Check the source code of the HTML. It is probably HTML5 placeholder if you only see the watermark in IE 10 or later. You can inject a text changed script for that input to remove the placeholder instead of dealing with TranslateAccelerator.